# Xcode doesn't upload the build

Tags: ios, xcode, flutter

I'm trying to release my first iOS app and I have everything prepared except the uploaded build. For that I'm using Xcode 12.0.1 (also updated to 12.1 and same error). Here you can see that I uploaded successfully a version:
[image]

[image]

The problem comes when I go to my Apple developer account and I see no builds:
[image]
[image]

Also Activity tab is empty:
[image]

Anyone having the same problem?

Comment: You are uploading version 1.4.4 but your version in App Store connect is 1.4.3. You need to change the version in App Store connect to 1.4.4 or upload a build for 1.4.3.  From the looks of your Xcode you have misunderstood the version vs the build number.  They don't need to be the same. A build must be unique within a version and the version number must match the version you have set in AppStore connect.

Comment: I just changed it to 1.4.4 but still not there

Comment: Check out the "activity" tab for the app in App Store connect. You may have to upload a new build that matches the version before you see it.  You should also eat an email from Apple telling you that either the build has finished processing or that there was a problem with the build.

Comment: The Activity tab is empty.

Comment: Added screenshot

Answer (score 1):

I checked my email and got an email from Apple saying that I was missing some information in my Info.plist:
[image]

So I added the key and compiled a new version again. Now I have some information in my Activity tab:
[image]

To see what is the permission for and add a proper message we can check this page:
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/bundleresources/information_property_list/nsmotionusagedescription

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same issue later I found that my app is using deprecated `UIWebview` instead of `WKWebView` that creates issues. Please check `UIWebview` is not used in code.

Answer (score 0):

Each build is going through an initial processing on iTunes - check "Activity" tab inside your Application - build you submitted should be visible there at first.

Once it goes through processing - you will see it under "build" tabs.

Also it seems you are checking wrong "Version" - make sure the iTunes version matches your build version - otherwise build will end up in "Activity" tab forever.

Comment: The Activity tab is empty. Added screenshot